# "This and this point(s)"

Tags: grammatical-number

I tend to say

> I don't feel comfortable with this and this **point**

where both *this* refer to points. Should I instead say

> I don't feel comfortable with this and this **points**?

Comment: Hi simpatico, welcome to English Language and Usage. This is a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. We aim to answer questions for people who understand and use English at a high level. This question seems quite basic. Please read [the FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) and enjoy learning about English through the rest of the site.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pluralize "point" to "points", you should rephrase the sentence as

> I don't feel comfortable with these points